# pydot has no attribute 'find graphviz'

Tags: python, theano, pydot

I'm running Anaconda, python 3.5 on a Windows 65-bit machine. I've already successfully run
conda install -c anaconda graphviz
as well as pydot.

After importing theano, pydot, and numpy, and instantiating the theano function f, when I try run

```
theano.printing.pydotprint(f, outfile='f.png',var_with_name_simple=True)
```

I get the AttributeError:

File "C:\Users\Me\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\printing.py", line 35, in 
    if pd.find_graphviz():

AttributeError: module 'pydot' has no attribute 'find_graphviz'

What's wrong?  Am I running a bad version of pydot?

--Ken

Comment: well, a 65-bit machine is pretty rare, I don't think theano supports it :)

Answer (score 1):

From a related issue on github https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/3210:
try installing `pydot-ng` instead of `pydot`.

Answer (score 0):

The function `find_graphviz` has been removed in `pydot == 1.2.3`. Please see [this `pydot` issue](https://github.com/erocarrera/pydot/issues/126) for more details. Instead, `pydot` searches for GraphViz executables in the `PATH` variable of the current environment.

Answer (score 0):

How exactly did you installed pydot?
Pip install of pydot only supports python 2.7 version, to the best of my knowledge.

For python 3+ you can try other versions of pydot avaiable at [Conda Cloud](https://anaconda.org/search?q=pydot%20). I used pydotplus:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pydotplus
```